# How can I plot a single point in MPAndroid chart (or ios-charts)

Tags: charts, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

When I plot a single point in MPAndroid chart (ios-charts) my point ends up to the very left of the graph. How can I center the graph when there is a single point?

P.S. I know this is iOS, the ios-charts library has similar usage so even if you have only used this library in Android your answer will still help a bunch.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thats easy:

- Add 3 x-axis values
- Add your Entry with x-index 1 (the middle)

Comment: I was thinking of doing this but I only have 1 x-axis value.

Comment: what should be the first and last x-axis value?